# CancellationTokenSource Constructor TimeSpan -1 msec magic value?

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

When contructing a CancellationTokenSource one can give a TimeSpan as a parameter or a number of milliseconds.

[MSDN CancellationTokenSource Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139229(v=vs.110).aspx)

There seems to be a magic value of -1 msec:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: delay.TotalMilliseconds is less than -1 or greater than Int32.MaxValue.

What does the special value of -1 msec mean?

Comment: This is common value for infinite time spans: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite(v=vs.110).aspx), it is the value for `Timeout.Infinite` in other words it will wait an infinite time before timing out.